# Como aumentar cada vez que presione un boton en PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Como puedo aumentar este valor "GE-00001" necesito que aumente el numero cada vez que presione un botón, estoy trabajando con php y js.

Comment: Bienvenido @Piero te invitamos a revisar https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask para tener una mejor redacción

Comment: Hola. puedes poner un poco de codigo ?  que has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: Ya tengo 00001 falta añadir GA- , el 00001 esta auto increment en mi base de datos asi que solo tendria que añadir el GA-